# Changing Wifi Mac Address in Nox Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, mac-address, mac-spoofing

I wanted to change Nox emulator mac address but it did not work at all

When I use their commands guidance and using the mac changer part to alter mac address, nothing happens, and when I check from device the mac address is the same as before, What is the problem and do you know any other solution to alter mac address only for emulator itself to be different than my main mac address?

Guidance: https://support.bignox.com/en/function/command

The command I used to alter the mac address:
NoxConsole.exe modify -name:NoxPlayer1 -mac:37:4a:40:27:e7:83

Answer (score 0):

(1) Change your NoxPlayer network setting to bridge mode

(2) Enter commands in PowerShell: (p.s. Change Nox_9 to your correct VM name index)

> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT"
> BigNoxVMMgr.exe modifyvm Nox_9 --macaddress2 000102030405